# visual studio でBeyond Compareを使用するには

Tags: visual-studio

コードの比較する際に[Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php)を使っています。これをVisual Studioのディフォルトの比較ツールとして指定するはどうすればいのでか？

Comment: StackOverflow本家の方に同様の質問に対しての回答がありますね。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare

Answer (score 1):

LainZero様のコメントで解決！！

StackOverflow本家の方に同様の質問に対しての回答がありますね。 [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466238/how-to-configure-visual-studio-to-use-beyond-compare]
LainZero